# What is the least issue prone way to separate the first set of numbers from a string?

Tags: javascript

For context, I have a system that asks a user to give a rating between 1-10. Afterwards, I give them the option to leave any additional notes they would like to leave.

Unfortunately what seems to happen half of the time is that a customer will leave notes along with the initial 1-10 rating. With the interface I am using I have no way of restricting the input to numbers only.

The best solution I would be going for is to simply separate the number from the statement into two separate variables or into an array[0-1].

So basically I have

```
var responseA = (customer input here)
```

Then I would need to remove any additional comments they put into the first response

```
responseA = responseA.someMagic() //This is where I need help
```

And continue to deal with the remaining interactions and store them as such

```
var responseB = responseA[1] + ". " + (customer input 2 here)
```

This will take the second portion of the first response that includes notes and combines those notes with the second response which contains the second portion of notes. If it's possible to have some sort of way to detect that there were notes in the first place that would also be good to avoid

```
". Thank you."
```

as opposed to

```
"Thank you."
```

Because of the concatenation of the first string in situations it is not necessary.

edit: After rereading this it still seems confusing if you don't know exactly what is going on. Let me show you a real world example:

> Q1: Please give a rating between 1-10:
>   "*10! You were very helpful, thank you!*"
>
> Q2: If you have any notes you may leave them here:
>   "*Very helpful.*"

This means that when the system that deals with the ratings from question 1 receives additional strings, it won't count it as a number. I want to remove everything after the 10 and add it to Q2's response to not lose any of their response, but also not store it in the wrong place.

Comment: Why don't you just use an [`<input type="number">` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number)? Or 10 radio buttons?

Comment: @melpomene: How do you know that the source is HTML?  And even if it is, can you not take seriously, "With the interface I am using I have no way of restricting the input to numbers only"?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I am taking it seriously, which is why I'm suggesting to use a different interface. I'm assuming HTML because OP is using JavaScript (why would you use JS if not to run in a browser?) and hasn't said anything to the contrary (and this is the sort of "confused newbie" question that would also fit with the incomplete tagging), and this seems like a NPS thing that would make sense on a web site.

Comment: @melpomene: Funny, I read it entirely differently.  As in "I have no choice but to use this interface."  Obviously it could be either, but I have experience with unchangeable data sources that I have to make the best of; that's probably why I heard it the way I did.  Note, thought, that JS is used in many places, not just in the browser.

Comment: @ScottSauyet You are correct, I am unable to use a different interface. HTML code does not help me in this scenario. I am passing strings from one server through to another which utilizes Javascript. The origin interface can't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility, using regex to check and split apart the first value:

```js
const combineResponses = (q1, q2) => {
  const matches = q1.match(/^(\d*)\W*(.*)/)
  return matches[2] ? {
    rating: matches[1],
    comment: [matches[2], q2].join('. ')
  } : {
    rating: matches[1],
    comment: q2
  }
}

console.log(combineResponses(
  "10! You were very helpful, thank you!", 
  "Very helpful."
))

console.log(combineResponses(
  "10", 
  "Very helpful."
))

console.log(combineResponses(
  "oops", 
  "Very helpful."
))
```

It does nothing to check that the rating is in the right range.  Nor does it handle, say `7.4`, although it would be easy enough to modify for the latter.

But if you can find a way to separate your initial input in a cleaner way, it would definitely be better to avoid this.

Comment: Your logic is technically broken: `rating: matches[1]` would throw an exception if `matches` is `null`. The only thing that saves you is that your regex always matches and the `matches &&` check is redundant.

Comment: What actually breaks is if the `q1` field contains multiple lines.

Comment: @melpomene: That's right.  Edited.  Although it might be better to have a better default if the first part doesn't match.  I just don't know the use case well enough to include one.

Comment: Yes, multiple lines might break this.  As I said, "a possible solution"

Comment: Regex is a great solution here, and will most likely help a lot of users if they have the same issue. However, since the only possibility is a number to be first, and not a string I am safe to use parseInt()

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the string will always begin with a number for the rating, you could call `parseInt()` on the string to find out what the number is. If there is a number, you could then use `indexOf()` to find the first time it appears and cut the string there, otherwise just assume the whole thing was a string.

```js
const userInputs = ['1 thank you', '10thanks', '  5.   random text', 'no rating'];

let length = 1;
let index;
let rating;
let response;

for (const i of userInputs) {
  rating = parseInt(i);
  
  if (rating) {
    if (rating > 9) {
      length = 2;
    }
    index = i.indexOf(rating);
    response = i.substring(index + length).trim();
  } else {
    response = i;
  }
  
  console.log(`${i}, rating: ${rating}, response: ${response}`);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like your idea. I used parseInt() to determine the first value in the string, I then used .toString() on that parsed int, then used the length of that string to separate the original input in two. This gives me two variables, one with the original first set of numbers, and the remaining comment. This works well because even if the input is "10/10" it will return strings "10" and "/10" which is exactly how I want it to go. Thank you for the answer! I didn't know of the existence of parseInt() somehow